# MVC3 / Razor Form Submission with Routes Mapped?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I have the following routes defined in my Global.asax:

```
    routes.MapRoute(name: "Home", url: "", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    routes.MapRoute(name: "CityStateResults", url: "{city}-{state}/{searchTerm}", defaults: new { controller = "Results", action = "SearchCityState" });
    routes.MapRoute(name: "CanadianProvinceResults", url: "CanadianProvinces/{state}/{searchTerm}", defaults: new { controller = "Results", action = "SearchCanadianProvinces" });
    routes.MapRoute(name: "AllCanadianResults", url: "Canada/{searchTerm}", defaults: new { controller = "Results", action = "SearchAllOfCanada" });
```

Now I want to write Razor form submission functionality that accepts two fields: txtSearchTerm and txtLocation.

txtLocation's format will always consist of [City, State], or [State] or [Country] and is database-driven, so no other values other than what is listed in the db will be accepted in that field.

If location is [City, State], I want the form to redirect to /City-State/searchTerm.
If location matches a state, I want to redirect to /CanadianProvinces/[state]/[searchterm].
If location matches a country, I want to redirect to /Canada/[searchterm].

I have a results controller with some actions setup, but unclear as to the first steps.  I'm sure I can do it with some client-side javascript and redirection, but I would like to know the standard way of doing this with C#, Razor and MVC3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the submission will be sent to the same controller which rendered the page. If not, you can use the ajax call to the specific controller/method to be targeted method. Put complex routing rules in the routing table is really hard to maintain.